# Why am I getting this "deployment target" warning from Xcode 6 in Yosemite?

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

I was using Yosemite public beta and now changed to the released version, but I still got this warning in my Xcode 6 projects:

> Apple LLVM 6.0 default OS X deployment target '10.10' for architecture 'x86_64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '10.9' for the OS X 10.9 SDK.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this error?

Comment: Any luck? I'm getting this now

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using the 10.9 SDK while requesting 10.10 as deployment target. Try to use the 10.10 SDK, it should fix this error.